# Is -Dmaven.test.skip=true and -DskipAllTests both the same?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am new to Maven. I guess there is a difference between these two. But can someone point out what exactly it is? Is the difference of different versions of Maven? Like previously any one of these was used and in the newer versions, the other one is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i cannot find **-DskipAllTests** but if you mean **-DskipTests** then my answer is:

No, these both are not the same.

**-Dmaven.test.skip=true** => skip test compilation and execution

**-DskipTests=true** => compile tests but skip their execution

i would strongly prefer do use **-DskipTests=true** over **-Dmaven.test.skip=true**

**BTW**:

There is also a property for skipping execution of integration tests (Tests ending with ***IT**):

**-DskipITs=true**

http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: Well thanks really a lot. That's quite a much needed help.

Comment: can you then accept the answer please? or do i forgot something ro answer?